# Glyphicons. What is relation between 'N' and '\e02d'? Is it possible to convert '\e02d' to 'N'?

Tags: android, textview, glyphicons, typeface

I am trying to use custom font in Android application. The font contains weather symbols. In my browser, I have found code for each symbol:

```
.climacon.moon:before {
  content: "\e02d";
}
```

When I am setting textview's text 'N' which in result is showing needed symbol (in this case 'moon')

Some other examples:

```
'I' - '\e028'
'F' - '\e025'
'X' - '\e037'
```

So my question is what is relation between 'N' and '\e02d'? If yes, how to convert '\e02d' to 'N'?

PS. Note that I am not asking how to set TextView's typeface

Answer (score 0):

`U+E02D` is in the [Unicode private-use area](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html). This means that the code points are available for arbitrary use by applications. In this case, the most likely explanation is that the specific font in use have special symbols at these points so that they can be easily displayed in text fields.